# Can ebpf only use kprobe to monitor kernel functions?

Tags: linux, kernel, ebpf, kprobe

I want to monitor a Linux kernel function using ebpf. Now, I write code using bcc like this:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3
# coding=utf-8
from bcc import BPF
from time import sleep
# define BPF program

bpf_program = """

int test_func(void  *ctx) {
    bpf_trace_printk("hello");
    return 0;
}
"""

# load BPF

b = BPF(text=bpf_program)
b.attach_kprobe(event="__x64_sys_getpid", fn_name="test_func")

while 1:
    sleep(100)
    b.trace_print()
```

This works fine and I know it's implemented based on kprobe.

But I wonder if I can only use kprobe to monitor any kernel function in ebpf?

Answer (score 1):

Mostly. Kprobes can attach to pretty much any function except for [blacklisted](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/trace/kprobes.html#kprobes-blacklist) functions.

> Kprobes can probe most of the kernel except itself. This means that there are some functions where kprobes cannot probe. Probing (trapping) such functions can cause a recursive trap (e.g. double fault) or the nested probe handler may never be called. Kprobes manages such functions as a blacklist. If you want to add a function into the blacklist, you just need to (1) include linux/kprobes.h and (2) use NOKPROBE_SYMBOL() macro to specify a blacklisted function. Kprobes checks the given probe address against the blacklist and rejects registering it, if the given address is in the blacklist.

Comment: Maybe also worth mentioning that many kernel functions are also inlined and thus can't be (easily) traced with kprobes.

Comment: how do i know which kernel function i want to probe? e.g. above example shows a kprobe being attached to `__x64_sys_getpid` event. is this a function in kernel? if i attach a function, what arguments the function can expect?